# terraform - how to return cidr blocks from data "external"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to use the data "external" to return a cidr block and feed it to  terraform resouce, for example, "resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls""

```
data "external" "get_ips" {
    program = ["python3", "get_ips.py"]

}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = "vpc-123"

  ingress {
    description = "TLS from VPC"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [data.external.get_ips.result.ipRanges]
 }


output of get_ips

default_ips = {
  "ipRanges": '"1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32"'
}
```

I got error:

```
Error: "\"1.1.1.1/32\", \"2.2.2.2/32\"" is not a valid CIDR block: invalid CIDR address: "1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32"

  on main.tf line 20, in resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls":
  20: resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
```

I wonder how to correctly return the return for the cidr blocks to use?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like `ipRanges` is a string, and I think you mean for it to be a list. See those single quotes? `'"1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32"'` your python code should return `["1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32"]`

Answer (score 1):

`cidr_blocks` should be a **list of strings**, not a single string. So it should be:

```
cidr_blocks = data.external.get_ips.result.ipRanges
```

Your `get_ips.py` returns `ipRanges` as **incorrect json string**:

```
'"1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32"'
```

But if you change it to

```
'["1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32"]'
```

you could use [jsondecode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsondecode.html) to turn it into correct list of strings:

```
cidr_blocks = jsondecode(data.external.get_ips.result.ipRanges)
```

Comment: thank you. I got it working with a test data as you suggested.

I actually got real result from a api call, and the example output is like this:

{
 "ipRanges": ["1.1.1.01/32", "2.2.2.2/32"],
 "ipv6Ranges": ["1234:1234::/32"],
}

but I am not sure how to manipulate the array value into something like this: '["1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32"]' so it would work as a valid cidr_blocks. Please advise.

Comment: @void If its map, you access it using key value "ipRanges". I'm not sure where "the example output" comes from? From your python code, the api you call, or it is from terraform?